# apps-script - Create new google doc in existing folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am creating a google doc from apps script as follows:

```
var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
```

I want this new document to be created in an existing folder in my drive. I  tried the following way:

```
var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder-id");
dir.addFile(newDoc);
```

But I get the error as:

```
ReferenceError: "DocsList" is not defined.
```

Is there any way to create a new document in my **existing folder** or move my file to an existing folder via apps script? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Folder.addFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfilechild) requires that you pass it a [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html), but [`DocumentApp.create()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname) returns a [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html). What you need to do is use [`newDoc.getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getid) to get its unique identifier, and then use it in [`DriveApp.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) to properly move the file.

```
var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(docName); // Create a Document
var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId()); // Get Document as File

var dir = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder-id"); // Get the folder
dir.addFile(docFile);  // Add the file to the folder

DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile); // Optionally remove the file from root
```

Please also note that Google Drive files can exist in multiple folders. So if you only want the file to be listed in the "folder-id" folder, then you'll need to remove it from the root folder where it was created by default.

Comment: Ohh that was easy, Thank you so much!!